# db2/sql query won't allow to select static value from join due to counts

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to figure out how to bypass an issue with a DB2 query I'm currently using.

This query:

```
SELECT
    count(*) as sales_180,
    180/count(*) as velocity

  FROM orders
        WHERE customerID= :cust_ID
        AND itemNum= :item
```

Works fine and returns the two values I want. However, I'm trying to do an inner join on the customerID on another table to get information related to it.

Due to the other values being based on a count of records, it won't let me select a static value from the other table.

```
SELECT
    count(*) as sales_180,
    180/count(*) as velocity
    c.customerCompany

  FROM orders o
      inner join customers c
         on o.customerID = c.customerID

  WHERE customerID= :cust_ID
  AND itemNum= :item
```

This tells me it won't let me select the value c.customerCompany since the first values are based on Counts.

Is there a way I can bypass this to select the c.customerCompany? I still want the counts, but I basically want to say "For this customer, get their company"

Comment: Can you include the exact error message from Db2?  You're missing a comma after `velocity`, and I wonder if you need a `GROUP BY customerID` in there.

Comment: sorry that was a typo, but my query does have the comma in it. The error is: Column c.customerCompany or expression in SELECT list not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issue in your query.

1. when you use aggregate function (`count`,`sum`,...) you must add non-aggregate columns in `group by`.
2. your `customerID` need to use `c.customerID` or  `o.customerID` otherwise, There are two columns name `customerID` from those two tables, let will let DB engine confused.

so you can try this.

```
SELECT
    count(*) as sales_180,
    180/count(*) as velocity,
    c.customerCompany
FROM orders o
  inner join customers c
     on o.customerID = c.customerID
WHERE c.customerID= :cust_ID AND itemNum= :item
GROUP BY c.customerCompany
```

**NOTE**

I would suggest you use indicates that the column specified for the query is explicitly specified